# Как поменять значение в столбце на основе условия к другому столбцу?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

Пытаюсь пробежаться по столбцу `кто`, и если там есть значение "2010", поменять значение в столбце `Марка` на "55п". При этом, другие значения в этом столбце должны оставаться нетронутыми.

Пробовал разные методы остановился на `replace`, но грамотно прописать не выходит.

Как правильно составить конструкцию?

Примерно представляю себе код так:

```
x['Марка'].replace(;, "55п", inplace=True) if x['кто'] == "2010"
```

| Кто | Кол | Марка |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2040 | 32 | 43л |
| 2010 | 44 | 88о |
| 2070 | 57 | 77ж |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Pandas подобные задачи делаются так:

1. сначала создается маска булевых значений для каждой строки - для тех строк, которые мы хотим изменить - `True`, для всех остальных `False`
2. заменяем значения в строках, отобранных по булевой маске из предыдущего пункта

Все это можно сделать однострочником:

```
df.loc[df["Кто"] == 2010, "Марка"] = "55п"
```